# Creating PKCS#12 container from input from stdin

Tags: pipe, encryption, openssl, certificates, stdin

I want to create a PKCS#12 (a.k.a PFX) container for a private key and a certificate using `openssl`.

My key and cert are contained in a single (unecnrypted) file:

```
$ cat d.pem
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIC/zCCAeegAwIBAgIUTSuL1tniz4LhTFSX5wRZ1e848tYwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEL
[...]
t+LT
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEvQIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKcwggSjAgEAAoIBAQDA0zDKJeOmZdsG
[...]
1PSc82v662N0NUTw0bELNGg=
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I can use this data with openssl if it is stored in a file, but not if I pipe it into openssl.

```bash
$ openssl pkcs12 -export -in d.pem -out test.p12
Enter Export Password:
Verifying - Enter Export Password:

$ cat d.pem |openssl pkcs12 -export -out test.p12
Could not read any certificates from -in file from <stdin>
```

According to the manpage, this should work:

```
-in filename|uri
           This specifies the input filename or URI.  Standard input is used by default.  With the -export option this is a file with
           certificates and a key, or a URI that refers to a key accessed via an engine.  The order of credentials in a file doesn't matter
           but one private key and its corresponding certificate should be present. If additional certificates are present they will also
           be included in the PKCS#12 output file.
```

How can I create a PKCS#12 container from input coming from stdin?

(I am using openssl v3.0.9)

Answer (score 1):

It seems your namesake [discussed this on github](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/10517) nearly three years ago.

The comment there on the order of parsing the combined certificate and key file lead me to swap them around, so that the private key is first in the file.

The command then works:

```
$ cat combined.pem
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----

$ cat combined.pem | openssl pkcs12 -export -out combined.p12
Enter Export Password:
Verifying - Enter Export Password:

$ ls -lh combined.p12
-rw------- 1 gareth gareth 2.6K Jul 10 13:44 combined.p12
```